# Create Object in Splash Screen to be used later

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listactivity, extends, implements

I read from a RSSfeed and create an object of that feed. As this takes time I want to have it read the feed during the spash screen. After the splash screen loads the Main Menu appears which extends TabActivity, after clicking a tab the next activity which which extends listActivity appears.

What is the best way to get the object from the spash screen to the 3rd Activity screen which extends the listActivity?

Answer (score 0):

you can start a service that can fetch the object, store it in the memory (or database, file, etc) and then use it whenever you want!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nah, What I did was create a control class and made it static. Instantiated it in the splash screen and referenced it later.

Thanks tho